# How can i replicate exactly this alignment in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i Have a Column that contains rows, in the rows, i want the second items in the all rows to be aligned as same with other second items in the row of other columns.

This picture will give a clearer view of what i want to achieve.

[image]

If you see this image you will notice how all second items in the all the rows have a definite start.

This is what i could achieve.

[image]

which is not exactly same because i had different values for each rows. as seen in my code below

```
Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22.0, top: 22.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Title',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 10,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Color(0xff34495E),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 55),
                          Text(
                            'Asoebi Gown',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              color: Color(0xff596780),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.2),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Quantity',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 10,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Color(0xff34495E),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: FractionallySizedBox(
                              widthFactor: 0.8,
                              child: Text(
                                '12',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xff596780),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.2),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Description',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 10,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Color(0xff34495E),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: FractionallySizedBox(
                              widthFactor: 0.9,
                              child: Text(
                                'Praesent vitae neque porta, hendrerit enim sed, temps ante. Suspendisse vitae massa neque. Praesent vitae neque porta, hendrerit enim sed, tempus ante.',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Color(0xff596780),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.2),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use expanded with flex value ratio, use the same left and right column ratio in all of the rows. I can write you if you want?

Comment: @HassanAli Please i'll appreciate if you can explain in writing

Comment: I see that you have accepted the answer. Do you still want solution?

Comment: Yes i do, because i encounter a problem : I am not able to put more than two children in a table row as it gives me an error, if there are other ways to handle this i'll really appreciate sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) widget.

```dart
  Table(
    border: const TableBorder(
      horizontalInside: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
    ),
    defaultColumnWidth: const IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
    children: const [
      TableRow(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Title'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Asoebi Gown'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      TableRow(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Quantity'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('12'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      TableRow(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Description'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
                'Praesent vitae neque porta, hendrerit enim sed, temps ante. Suspendisse vitae massa neque. Praesent vitae neque porta, hendrerit enim sed, tempus ante.'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```

You can specifically specify the `horizontalInside` borders to draw the dividers. By providing a `IntrinsicColumnWidth()`, you tell the column to take up the size of its largest cell. If you want this behavior to be different across columns, you can also set the `columnWidths` and provide a different type of width for each column.

Comment: I wrapped my tale with padding to make sure the dividers are padded accordingly, thank you!

Comment: Hello sir, how do i add more than 2 children in a table row?

Comment: it depends, do you want to make a third column or do you want one of the two cells to contain two widgets? The linked documentation page contains the necessary information